# How to send confirmation request from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I could use some help. I'm building a Rails app with Devise with the following models:

User (devise)

- has_many :jobs
- has_many :children

Child

- belongs_to :user
- has_many :jobs
- has_one :account

Job

- belongs_to :user
- has_many :children

Account

- belongs_to :child

Once the child has completed the job, I want to send a confirmation request to the User, so that when the User confirms, the value of the job is added to the Child's Account. I'm just a bit stuck on how to manage that request. Any help would be awesome, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a Boolean "confirmed" field to the Job model with "false" as a default value. 
When the child completes the job, the record is saved in the database with the value  confirmed: false. 
Then you can arrange your controllers so that the User can see the jobs which are pending (confirmed: false, i.e created but not confirmed) and have the possibility to confirm the job creation or to refuse it (destroy).

```
pending_jobs = Jobs.where(confirmed :false)
```

Then you can list the jobs which are confirmed and display them the way you want.

```
jobs = Job.where(confirmed: true)
```

Its a bit of a workaround but makes it easy to handle and display jobs records.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did this (pretty much) using pending instead of confirmed and created an extra index (pending.html.erb) which shows all job with pending. Then I added a simple form in that index attached to each job with `pending == true`. The form, when submitted, will change both pending => false and completed = true. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad that I could help and the way you adapted it with pending/completed seems nice! :)